# Finding prime numbers kdb, discussion about projection and functions

Tags: function, primes, kdb

So I am trying to create a function that finds all the prime numbers below a certain number.

This is the code I have written which doesn't work, but will help me explain how I am trying to solve it. I will fix the manual checking for 0,1,2 later.

```
primes: enlist 2
g: h[;primes]
g'[3 + til 100-2]

h:{[x;y] z: x mod/: y; bool:(0 in z)=0b; if[bool; `primes set primes,x ]; }
```

So what I want to do is, use the each `(')` operator to run this function `h` for each element in `3+ til 100-2`. However, I want it to continue using the primes variable not in an `each` way. The if statement will execute if there is no `0` in `z` as this means `x` is prime. Then in the if statement, I would like to join `x` to the primes list.

Loop 1: `x:3 y: enlist 2`
In the if statement, it will join 3 to `primes`

loop 2: `x:4 y: 2 3`
if statement will not execute

loop 3: `x:5 y: 2 3`
In the if statement, it will join 5 to `primes`

loop 4: `x:6 y: 2 3 5`
if statement will not execute

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic works, and can be tidied up a little as:

```
q)primes:enlist 2
q)h:{m:x mod/:primes;bool:(0 in m)=0b;if[bool;`primes set primes,x];}
q)h'[3 + til 100-2];
q)primes
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

Some differences to yours:

1. If you project your `h` with input `primes`, e.g. `g:h[;primes]` then that `primes` input is fixed at that point in time, it will not vary for each iteration. So your `y` in your function is always fixed at just `2`.

I got around that in this example by simply referencing the global `primes` variable (which isn't fixed).

2. I avoided using `z` as a variable within the function as it is generally bad practice since `z` is more commonly used as the default/implicit third input variable in a function.

Sticking with your logic, a more conventional iterative approach which doesn't require a global `primes` variable would be:

```
q){$[not 0 in y mod/:x;x,y;x]}/[2;3 + til 100-2]
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

This uses `over` (`/`) to iterate.

This still isn't the optimal way to get primes, for that this might be optimal: https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/blob/master/greplin.q#L6

```
q)p:{$[x<4;enlist 2;r,1_where not any x#'not til each r:p ceiling sqrt x]}
q)p 100
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

Comment: You've put x,y in the true statement of the vector condition. Can I ask how that works because you're not assigning that to anything so how does it know that it is x for the next iteration.

Comment: That's how `over` (`/`) works....the output from one iteration (in my case `x,y`) becomes the `x` input for the next iteration. You can see it in an example such as `{0N!(x;y)}/[1;2 3 4];`

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to find prime numbers, but it is hard to beat [Eratosthenes’ sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), which avoids arithmetic operations such as `mod`.

Below, the function `es` takes a sieve function `s` as its first argument and as its second, the number `N` to find primes below.

The sieve’s argument is a pair: a list of known primes, and a boolean vector flagging in `til N` the integers yet to eliminate. It simply finds the next uneliminated number and eliminates its multiples.

```
sieve:{n:1+y?1b;(x,n;y and count[y]#10b where(n-1),1)}.
```

Applied as a unary, it can be used with the [While iterator](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/accumulators/#while) `/`.
To apply the sieve we give it an initial state `(2;0b,1_N#10b)` and stop when there are no primes left to test below `sqrt N`. The result is the primes found, and the non-multiples: `{x,1+where y}.` combines them.

```
es:{[s;N]{x,1+where y}. ({any z#y}[;;"j"$sqrt N].)s/ (2;0b,1_N#10b)}
```

This is a bit faster and a lot less memory-hungry than the `p` function in the accepted answer:

```
q)X:2000000
q)p:{$[x<4;enlist 2;r,1_where not any x#'not til each r:p ceiling sqrt x]}
q)(p X)~es[sieve]X
1b
q)\ts:10 p 2000000
726 471865536
q)\ts:10 es[sieve] 2000000
399 8391296
```

These and other functional algorithms for finding primes are discussed in Part 1 of [Finding primes with q](https://www.5jt.com/finding-primes-with-q).